# why does workflow creates folder instead of Document set in sharepoint onlne?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

am creating Document set using SPD workflow-2013  but it is creating folder instead of Document-set,why it is happening?I have made setting like bellow
 **Library Setting->Advance setting->Allow management of content types?->Yes** 

after that am setting Document Set content type by following bellow steps
**Library Setting->Add from existing site content types->selecting document set from Available Site Content Types->add->ok**

and my workflow is like bellow snap
[image]

and starting workflow on item created action